# insert in database table in python

Tags: python, mysql, json

im a beginner in python and i have this project where i neeed to classify tweets into different categories
i have created a tweet table in mysql database that contains these following attributes:(tweet_id,id_user,text,tweet_location,created_at,name_screen,
categorie_name) where they will be inserted by the informations in every tweet that corresponds to them

but i keep receiving this error :

```
 line 43, in <module>
    data['user_screen_name'],data['cat'])
KeyError: 'cat'
```

data['cat'] is already declared in another program witch executes the classification in the same directory

do i need to connect the two programs or ?
any help would be really appreciated

```
import mysql.connector
import json
# create the key

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port='3306', user='root', password='nihad147', database='tweets')
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql_tweet = """INSERT INTO tweet (  tweet_id,
                                    id_user,
                                    text,
                                    tweet_location,
                                    created_at,
                                    name_screen,
                                    categorie_name,
                                    )
                                    VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
c = 0
for line in myJsonFile:
    c = c + 1
    print("tweet number ", c, " is uploading to the server")
    data = json.loads(line)
    # insert into tweet



    val_tweet = (
        data['tweet_id'], data['user_id_str'], data['raw_text'], data['location']['address']['city'], data['date'],
        data['user_screen_name'],data['cat'])
    print('nihad')
    mycursor.execute(sql_tweet, val_tweet)

    mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to debug you're code you can add

```
print(data)
```

before insert into tweet to find out document keys and values

also you can use from `data.get("date", None)` instead of data["date"] this code returns None value if `date` key no exists instead of raise error